# issue with arrange content in pdf with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, jspdf

I am trying to download pdf with jquery but when I download pdf it showing content

[image]

for that I have make below code

```js
{ 
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',  title: 'Customer Sales Rep Sales Totals', orientation: 'landscape',
                footer: true,
                action: newPDFAction,
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible',                    
                    order: 'applied',
                    modifier: {
                        pageMargins: [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], // try #3 setting margins
                        margin: [ 10,0 ], // try #4 setting margins
                        alignment: 'center'
                    }, 
                    body : {
                        margin:[10,0],
                        pageMargins: [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                        alignment: 'center'
                    } // try #5 setting margins          
                    ,columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] //column id visible in PDF    
                },customize: function (doc) 
                {
                    doc.content[1].table.widths = [ '15%', '15%', '10%','10%','10%', '15%', '15%' ,'10%'];
                    doc.content[1].borders = ['2px solid'];
                    doc.content[1].fillColor = '#ccc';
                    doc.content.splice(0,0);
                }
            }
```

I don't know why it is showing like this. html is showing properly while I am hitting this html in browser

can anybody help me in this?

Comment: do you have the `html` in table format? If so, kindly have a look here the `data-table` export buttons  https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: @mehmoodkhan Thank You for your reply. I am using datatable only but when I use datatable and implement download pdf in that it is downloading particular page records only and I want to download all records of datatable so that I have made custom pdf implementation function

Comment: You can do this by removing the `pagination` from your table, to have all records of your table

Comment: @mehmoodkhan but I have to add pagination because there are huge amount of records that datatable have